# Spring MVC: Required String parameter 'code is not present

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting the following error:

> Required String parameter 'code' is not present.

I want to retrieve the person's code when I enter the email and password data, i.e. I have the following query:

```
SELECT code FROM authentication WHERE email=? AND password=?
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView customerLogin(@RequestParam("code") String code,@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCode(code);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        customer.setPassword(password);

        String name = customerDao.loginCustomer(customer);
        String cf=customer.getCode();

        if (name != null) {

            mv.setViewName("redirect:/update/" +cf);

        } else {

            mv.addObject("msg", "Invalid user id or password.");
            mv.setViewName("login");
        }

        return mv;

    }
```

Dao:

```
@Override
        public String loginCustomer(Customer customer) {
            
            String sql = "SELECT code FROM authentication WHERE email=? AND password=?";
            
            List<String> customers = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[] {customer.getCode(), customer.getEmail(), customer.getPassword() },String.class);
            if (customers.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return customers.get(0);
            }
        }
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="login" method="post">
        <pre>
        
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
    
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </pre>
    </form>
    ${msg}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you passing code here? `jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[] {customer.getCode(), customer.getEmail(), customer.getPassword() },String.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is obvious: you do not pass `code` parameter into your controller method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView customerLogin(@RequestParam("code") String code,
        @RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    
    }
```

In order to solve this issue, you have two ways:

a. make `code` not required, thus we need to add `required=false` in controller method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView customerLogin(@RequestParam(value = "code", required=false) String code,
        @RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {


    }
```

b. add `code` field in your html form:

<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    <pre>
    
    Code: <input type="text" name="code" />

    Email: <input type="text" name="email" />

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </pre>
</form>
${msg}
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception happening at controller level. You are not passing the code Param in the URL.